# A question related to reflexive rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring. An endomorphism $\alpha:R\to R$ is said to be right central reflexive if for all $a,b\in R,$ $aRb=(0)\implies bR\alpha (a)\subset Z(R)$, where $Z(R)$ denotes the centre of the ring.

The ring $R$ is called right $\alpha$-central reflexive if $\alpha$ is a right central endomorphism for $R$.

Let us consider a statement as follows:

For all $a,b\in R$, $aR\alpha (b)=(0)\implies bRa\subset Z(R)$.....(*)

It can be proved that if $\alpha:R\to R$ is onto, (*) implies $R$ is right central $\alpha$-reflexive. I want to show show that surjectivity of $\alpha$ is not superfluous. But I could not find an into endomorphism $\alpha$ such that $(*)$ holds but $R$ is not a right central $\alpha$-reflexive ring.

Please help me in this regard.